# How can I wear my hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I can't find how to wear my hat. I read the [FAQ](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq) but I can't find the option.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I asked a new question reporting what you reported here and in comments.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to [your profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/28275/adrian-cid-almaguer?tab=profile).
2. Click your profile picture.
3. Select a hat.
4. Drag the hat around on your profile picture until it's in the right spot (or select "show controls" and use those tools to move/resize).
5. When you're done, click "Wear hat".
6. Be merry :)